Logical formula in nonstandard analysis (Nelson's IST)
I have no proper knowledge of axiomatic set theory or logic, so please forgive my ignorance. I am reading a book on Nonstandard Analysis (for fun, mostly), in particular Nelson's version of NSA using Internal Set Theory, but the axioms confuse me.
For instance, the Idealization Principle is formulated as
$$
\forall^{st.fin.} F \exists x \forall y \in F[R(x,y) \text{ holds}] \iff \exists x' \forall^{st.} y[R(x',y) \text{ holds}],
$$
where $R$ is any classical (or internal) relation.
From my understanding, the variables $x,x',y,F$ are supposed to range over all possible sets, not just sets in the domain of $R$ (this point is never spelled out in the books/articles that I have seen, so I'm not sure). However, I don't think my understanding is correct since it'd make the right hand side trivially false, e.g. if $R(x,y)$ means $x,y \in \Bbb N$ and $x>y$, the Idealization Principle should prove that $\exists x'$ such that  $x' > y$ for all $y\in \Bbb N$, but
$$
\exists x' \forall^{st.} y[R(x',y) \text{ holds}]
$$
is trivially false if we consider a standard set $y \notin \Bbb N$ (because $R(x,y) $ doesn't hold for any $x$ in this case).
This led me to think that perhaps the part $[R(x,y) \text{ holds}]$ should be interpreted as
$$
(x,y) \in \text{dom} R \implies (x,y) \in R
$$
to guarantee that the inputs $x,y$ are valid (e.g. $\text{dom} R = \Bbb N \times \Bbb N$ in our previous example). This interpretation cannot be correct either since if it is the case, then
$$
\exists x' \forall^{st.} y[R(x',y) \text{ holds}]
$$
would always be trivially true since we can just take $x'$ outside the domain of $R$.
I understand that the books/articles I've seen try not to be too formal, but the attempt to be less formal confuses me instead. I'd really appreciate if anyone could clarify what the axiom actually means.

But in your example, both sides of the $\iff$ are false.

@AlexKruckman Yes, so how can it be used to deduce the existence of a nonstandard $x \in \Bbb N$ if the statement is a tautology due to the fact that both sides of $\iff$ are false?

The fact that you get no information from the biconditional when $y\not\in\mathbb N$ is a feature, not a bug. It does not preclude the fact that you do get information when $y\in\mathbb N$, which is all we care about. Your fiddling around with domains is equivalent to the fact that we get no information when $y\not\in\mathbb N$. I am also not sure how Nelson is written, but typically in this context we do not talk about relations, and instead talk about predicates/propositions-with-free-variables, in which case talking about "domains" makes no sense.

@NicholasTodoroff Perhaps that's how it's meant to be interpreted. I don't really know the difference between predicates/propositions-with-free-variables and (set-theoretic) relations, to be honest, which is likely the source of my confusion. Could you please clarify what you meant regarding getting "no information" when $y \notin \Bbb N$? I (clearly mistakenly) thought I'd get False $\iff$ False, which is a tautology, in that case.

In ordinary set theory there is not much difference between relations and predicates, but IST demands careful attention to the difference between internal predicates (i.e. not mentioning "standard") and external predicates, and only internal predicates can be safely confused with relations.

@BigbearZzz A (binary) predicate is a string of variables and logical symbols which forms a syntactically correct sentence, and where two of the variables are not bound by quantifiers $\forall$ or $\exists$, i.e. they are free. Any objects can be substituted for the free variables, and the resulting proposition is either true of false. There is no notion of "domain" or "codomain". A (binary) relation, in math, is usually defined as a triple of sets $(R,A,B)$ such that $R$ is a subset of the Cartesian product $A\times B$, with $A$ called the domain and $B$ the codomain.

@NicholasTodoroff So in my example for $R$, if a set $F$ (from the left hand side of $\iff$) contains some $y \notin \Bbb N$, then it is considered `not admissible' and we get no information?

That's not what I was saying, I was just clarifying the difference between predicates and relations, essentially because there is no need to talk about "domains" at all.

By "no information", what you wrote before is exactly what I mean: when $y\not\in\mathbb N$ you trivially get $\mathrm{False}\iff\mathrm{False}$, which is trivially true and we've gained no information. When $y\in\mathbb N$ and $\neg\mathrm{st}(y)$ then the same comment holds: $R(x',y)$ is still trivially true, so it gives no information. When $y\in\mathbb N$ and $\mathrm{st}(y)$, now $R(x',y)$ is not trivially true, so the declaration "$R(x',y)$ is true" tells us something meaningful about $x'$ and $y$.

Regarding your "This interpretation cannot be correct..." sentence, you've inserted domains/codomains wrong. It would look like $$\exists x'(x'\in\mathrm{dom}(R)\land\forall^{\mathrm{st}}y[y\in\mathrm{codom}(R)\implies R(x',y)]).$$ $\mathrm{dom}(R)$ is the set the first argument of $R$ belongs to, and $\mathrm{codom}(R)$ is the set the second argument belongs to.

@NicholasTodoroff I'm trying to understand the rest of your answer. As for the part about the existence of $x'$, I was saying that it'd always exist if we define "$R(x,y)$ holds" to be $(x,y) \in \text{dom} R\times \text{codom} R  \implies (x,y) \in R$ (which is not the correct definition) since $\text{dom} R$ cannot contain all possible sets.

@NicholasTodoroff You latest comment makes more sense than what I have been reading in the books so far, I'd have no problem understanding if it's phrased like this. I am still trying to understand why it's equivalent to the version that I wrote, where we allow the variables $x,x',y,F$ to range over any set.

@NicholasTodoroff Maybe I should break my question down even more. Let's consider only this part of the statement (with $R$ as before):
$$
\exists x' \forall^{st.} y[R(x',y) \text{ holds}]
$$
It is a sentence with no free variable, so we can decide its truth value. I am struggling to understand why this statement is not false. It asserts the existence of a set $x'$ such that $R(x',y)$ is true for all standard set $y$. I'd think that if I pick $y_0$ such that $y_0 \notin \Bbb N$, then $R(x',y)$ cannot be true, so the assertion that $x'$ exists is false. Why am I wrong about this?

$
\newcommand\N{\mathbb N}
$I've made a terrible mistake by not paying enough attention to what you've written. I'm sorry for leading you in directions that are not really relevant.
You are correct that if
$$
  R(x,y) \equiv x,y\in\mathbb N\land x>y
$$
then nothing is accomplished. It still trivially satisfies Idealization, since we get a tautology like you say.
The problem is that this is the wrong predicate. Something good to know is that statements like "there exists $x\in A$ such that $P(x)$" are formally written
$$
  \exists x[x\in A\land P(x)],
$$
and statements like "for all $y\in A$, we have $P(y)$" are formally written
$$
  \forall y[y\in A\implies P(y)].
$$
The notation using brackets for quantifier scope gets extremely cumbersome; I will instead use a notation where we follow quantifiers by a period and have them scope over the entire rest of the sentence, like so
$$
  \exists x.\:x\in A\land P(x),\quad \forall y.\:y\in A\implies P(y).
$$
So the kind of statement we want is
$$
  \exists x.\:x\in\N\land(\forall^{\mathrm{st}}y.\:y\in\N\implies x>y).
$$
Less formally, "there exists an $x$ in $\N$ such that for all standard $y$ in $\N$ we have that $x > y$".
It stands to reason that we have a tautology $P\land[\forall y.Q(y)] \equiv \forall y.P\land Q(y)$, so the above is the same as
$$
  \exists x\forall^{\mathrm{st}}y.\:x\in\N\land(y\in\N\implies x>y).
$$
(It's annoying to write out all the details with what's going on with the $\mathrm{st}$, but it suffices to say that $\forall^{\mathrm st}y.Q(y)\equiv\forall y.\mathrm{st}(y)\implies Q(y)$ and to work from there.)
So the correct $R$ for what we want is
$$
  R(x, y) \equiv x\in\mathbb N\land(y\in\N\implies x>y).
$$

I see now, thanks! It's nice to know that there is a way to formally convert $\forall x \in X. P(x)$ to $\forall x. P'(x)$ (same for $\exists$) in order to get the correct $P'$.

Using the transformations here, am I correct in thinking that the Idealization axiom implies
$$
\forall^{st.fin.} F \exists x \in X \forall y \in F\cap Y. R(x,y) \iff \exists x' \in X \forall^{st.} y \in Y. R(x',y),
$$
where $X,Y$ are some fixed sets (in our case $X = Y = \Bbb N$)? Is the left hand side equivalent to
$$
\forall^{st.fin.} F\subset Y \exists x \in X \forall y \in F. R(x,y)
$$
or not?

@BigbearZzz Yes on both counts. In fact, this very form with $X,Y$ assumed standard is used for the Bounded Idealization axiom of Bounded Set Theory (BST), a better-behaved alternative to IST. Specifically, see exercise 3.1.7(ii) of Nonstandard Analysis, Axiomatically by Kanovei and Reeken, or page 273 of Analysis with Ultrasmall Numbers by Hrbacek, Lessmann, and O'Donovan (this one has unbounded $\exists$, but that is easily seen to not matter).

While it is implied by Idealization, I don't think it is equivalent (even without restrictions on $X,Y$) because of the unbounded $\forall$'s in Idealization.

Another quick question, if you don't mind. Am I correct in understanding that
$$
\forall^{st.fin.} F\subset Y \exists x \in X \forall y \in F. R(x,y) \equiv \forall^{st.fin.} F \exists x \in X \forall y \in F\cap Y. R(x,y)
$$
because every subsets of a standard and finite set are also standard and finite? (here $X, Y$ need not be standard)

@BigbearZzz "because every subsets of a standard and finite set are also standard and finite?" You're asking this because $F\cap Y\subseteq F$? Then yes because $\forall y\in F.\mathrm{st}(y)$, which in fact you could use as a definition of "standard finite set".

Very interesting, thanks. Yes, I was asking because I wasn't completely certain if $F \cap Y$ would also be standard or not. Is it true in general that a subset of a standard set is also standard? So far, I've seen that elements of a standard set need not be standard.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
